# More Depth on how getline works

Tags: c++, input, stream, getline

So for example if I had a .dat file like this

```
410000 1905 7 50
410001 2015 3 25 
410023 1857 12 -25
```

I am trying to figure out how to store these numbers into a linked list, which i understand the linked list, but on cases where the .dat might look like

```
410000 1905 7 50
410001 2015 3 25 
410023 1857 12
```

where the last line only has 3 values, I am not quite sure how to get those values. what i originally had was.

```
while(filename >> location >> year >> month >> temp)
```

but i was wondering if there were only 3 values on that line, would i get an error or would the temp value be taken off the next line, and since I did not think that would work, i wondered how getline works, and so I thought that maybe i could try

```
while ( getline(filename,location,year,month,temp))
```

and i was wondering what would happen if that while loop hit the line with 3 values instead of 4. 
So if anyone could possibly explain how I could get around the problem, any help is appreciated.

If there are only 3 values on a line i must tell the user there is an error, but keep checking all the other values, i cannot just return 0; and exit the program.

Comment: Getline allows you to get a string till the \n character on a stream or overload to what character it goes to.

Comment: Also your current code with getline would not work.

Comment: is that because it has location, month, year, temp and can only take 1 extra argument

Comment: The syntax is getline(stream, string) or getline(stream, string, char)

Comment: `getline`, as the name suggests, **gets** a **line**. Typically, you read a line into a string, then create a `std::istringstream` from that string, and use extractors to get the values from the string; repeat until done.

Comment: so would i want to use getline, then seperate the values by the spaces then check to see if there are 4, and then convert them to int?

Answer (score 0):

[`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) reads a full line from an `istream`. Your loop would look like:

```
string line;  
while (getline(file,line)) {
    // parse the string in line to extract the compnents
    ... 
}
```

One way to decompose `line` is to use a [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/?kw=stringstream):

```
    stringstream is(line);  
    is >> location >> year >> month >> temp;
```

If an error would happen in the format of the line, the state of `is` would be changed accordingly.